# how to show the json in frontend using angular 4

Tags: json, angular

I am new to angular 4. I am facing problem in showing JSON in my html view. I have following json.

```
{"result":[
{"role_id":124,"role_name":"ramesh","roles":"user"},
{"role_id":123,"role_name":"suresh","roles":"admin"}
]
}
```

**component file**

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  data: Object;
  loading: boolean;
  credentials: Credentials;
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.credentials = new Credentials();
  }
  login():void{
    console.log(this.credentials);

    this.loading = true;
    this.data = {};
    this.http.request('http://localhost:8080/api/Sampledata')
      .subscribe((res: Response) => {
        this.data = res.json();
        this.loading = false;
        console.log(this.data)
      });

  }
}
```

**Html File**

```
<h2>Basic Request</h2>
    <button type="button" (click)="login()">Make Request</button>
    <div *ngIf="loading">loading...</div>
    <pre>{{data | json}}</pre>
```

I am getting the json in front end like this.
[Front End Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv6Iv.jpg)

I want to get **role_name** separately so i tried changing the html file like this

```
<h2>Basic Request</h2>
    <button type="button" (click)="login()">Make Request</button>
    <div *ngIf="loading">loading...</div>
    <pre>{{data?.role_name}}</pre>
    </div>
```

What is the right way to display just the role_name?

Comment: You have multiple `role_name`s, I suppose you'd want to show them all?

Comment: What `role_name`? You have one for each object in your array...

Comment: `data.result[0]?.role_name`

Comment: @Vikas That would have to be `data.result[0].role_name`

Comment: @ Robby Cornelissen Oops My bad I missed it Thanx for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access a particular element using index

```
<h2>Basic Request</h2>
    <button type="button" (click)="login()">Make Request</button>
    <div *ngIf="loading">loading...</div>
    <pre>{{data.result[0]?.role_name}}</pre>
    </div
```

and if you want to list out all the names use `*ngFor`

```
<h2>Basic Request</h2>
        <button type="button" (click)="login()">Make Request</button>
        <div *ngIf="loading">loading...</div>
         <pre *ngFor="let r of data.result">{{r.role_name}}</pre>
     </div>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-an41bm)**

Answer (score 1):

you can use `*ngFor` because data is in array of object.

```
<pre *ngFor="let res of data.result">{{res.role_name}}</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do as below to list donw each property of you object

```
.subscribe((res: Response) => {
        this.data = res.json();
       if(this.data.result && this.data.result.length > 0)
        this.objekeys = Object.keys(this.data.result[0]);
        this.loading = false;
        console.log(this.data)
      });

<table>
   <tr *ngFor="let data of data.result">  
     <td *ngFor="let key of objekeys">
       <span>key </span> <span>data[key]</span>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```